# G-Suite email with custom domain also used for hosting at Digital Ocean. How?

Tags: dns, gmail, google-workspace

I would like to know before hand, if it is possible to host my custom domain at domains.google, use this custom domain to for Gsuite custom emails while being able to point the domain to Digital Ocean to use it for webhosting as well.

Is this possible?